# How to delete or show details about an Object contained in list and presented in dataTable using JSF framework?

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, arraylist, faces-config

I want to know if someone of you have any idea or solution about problem concerning how to show detail or delete an object presenting in a dataTable ?

I display data from database using MySql in jsf as a dataTable with columns containing commandLink for show detail and commandButton for deleting this object , all objects are contained in a Arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{MyBean.myList}" var="item" >
<f:facet name="header">
  <h:outputText value="This is 'dataTable' demo" />
</f:facet>
<h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
  <h:outputText value="name"/>
  </f:facet> 
   <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"></h:outputText>
</h:column>
```

...

in your button code :

```
<h:column><h:commandButton value="delete" action="#{MyBean.delete}" /></h:column>
```

Your backing-bean :

```
 private DataModel<Item> myList = new ListDataModel<Item>(items);

 public void delete() {
    items.remove(myList.getRowData());
 }
```

Comment: the backbean implementation will be different if you use Seam framework with JSF , or JSF alone.